# Yii2 ActiveForm Отправка формы после второго клика

Tags: yii2, activeform

Есть форма, которая подгружается аяксом на страницу в модалку. Проблема в том, что форма отправляется после второго клика на кнопку submit. Заметил, что при первом нажатии добавляются класс has-success ко всем полям в форме. Попробовал сначала добавить класс, потом отправить форму и она отправилась с первого раза. Кто-нибудь сталкивался с таким?
Код:

```
public function actionViewCheck($userId, $projectId, $page = 1)
{
    $project = MyProjects::findOne($projectId);
    $line = PostsLine::find()->where(['project_id' => $projectId])->andWhere(['social' => 5])->all();
    if (Yii::$app->request->post()) {
        $checkboxes = Yii::$app->request->post('checkbox');
        foreach ($checkboxes as $key => $checkbox){
            $line = PostsLine::findOne($key);
            if ($line->check != $checkbox){
                $line->check = $checkbox;
                $line->save();
                    if ($line->check){
                        $project->updateCounters(['done' => 1]);
                    }elseif(!$line->check){
                        $project->updateCounters(['done' => -1]);
                    }
            }
        }
        return $this->redirect(['project-list','page' => $page]);
    }
    return $this->renderAjax('_form', [
        'line' => $line,
        'userId' => $userId,
        'projectId' => $projectId,
    ]);
}
//форма:
<div class="blocks">
    <? $form = ActiveForm::begin([
        'action' => '/personal-area/view-check',
        'enableAjaxValidation' => true,
    ])?>
        <?foreach ($line as $item){ ?>
            <?if (gmdate('Y-m-d', strtotime("-6 days")) <= $item->date && gmdate('Y-m-d') >= $item->date){?>
            <?=$form->field($item, 'check')
                ->checkbox(['name' => 'checkbox['.$item->id.']', 'id' => $item->id,'label' => '<span>'.$item->post_id.'</span>','labelOptions' => [
                    'class' => 'checkbox -custom rules'],
                ])?><br>
                <?}?>
        <?}?>
    <?= Html::submitButton('Проверить', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary'])?>
    <? $form = ActiveForm::end()?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Добрый день. Класс has-success в activeform означает что поле прошло валидацию.
Для начала удалите вот это  'enableAjaxValidation' => true. Валидация у вас вообще не заданна. А вообще присмотритесь к  полю checkboxList. Генерируете массив  items  по вашим условиям, и передаете его checkboxList дергаете его. 
Пример метода:

```
public function itemsList(){
        return   ArrayHelper::map(Item::find()->select(['name'])->asArray()->all(),'id','name');
}
```

В форме:
$form->field($model,'items')->checkboxList($model->itemsList())->label(false)